# How can I set the kernel for CreatePalette?

Tags: parallelization, palettes

I have written some code that requests some calculations from an SQL server every N seconds and uses a palette:

```
CreatePalette[Dynamic[DateListPlot[...]]]
```

I create many copies of this notebook, each with different parameters, and launch as many independent kernels.

But there is a problem. Frist, I launch the 1st palette on kernel1. Next, I start a 2nd palette on kernel2, (Evaluation->Notebook Kernel), but when I do that, the first palette thinks that its kernel is kernel2.

How can I set the kernel for `CreatePalette` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have configured kernels "Kernel1" and "Kernel2", then this just works:

```
CreatePalette[test, Evaluator -> "Kernel1"]

CreatePalette[test2, Evaluator -> "Kernel2"]
```